# Linux rights across mounted shares

Tags: remote, cifs

I need some tutelage on the rights across  unix. I could swear  this has never been a problem but for some reason something is failing.

On a NAS there is media share.  I have set the permissions to 777 to avoid potential issues.

On a client i mount that share via FSTAB

//192.168.1.2/root /mnt/NasOne cifs username=USER1,password=PASS1,sec=ntlm,_netdev 0 0

The share mounts fine, however I get permission denied when i try to create a file. although the directory rights are listed as drwxrwxrwx  for the folder.

as a test, I have created a users with the same name on the NAS and placed him in the sudo group and mounted the share as that user. but that made no difference

What i am missing?

Comment: files are actually being created. when ls > a.txt is execute.  a.txt is created with a user and group of 98. when i see it on the NAS the users and group are listed as admin for users and group.